# initialize a static member with a file

Tags: c++, arrays, static, fstream

I have a dictionary class , for spell checking . I have an array as the list of words , and I must initialize it with a file that there are words in it . 
my problem is that , I need my wordlist variable to be a static variable , cause only one of it is enough for any other extra object created from the dictionary class and it is logical , however there is no need for a second object of the class , but what if we needed more than one object? is there a way?

```
#ifndef DICTIONARY_H
#define DICTIONARY_H

class Dictionary
{
public:
    static const int SIZE = 109582;
    Dictionary();
    bool lookUp(const char *)const;
private:
    void  suggestion(const char *)const;
    char *wordList[SIZE];
};

#endif
```

wordlist must be static ...

I only can think of this kind of defining ...

```
  Dictionary::Dictionary()
    {
        ifstream inputFile("wordsEn.txt", std::ios::in);

        if (!inputFile)
        {
            cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
            throw;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE && !inputFile.eof(); ++i)
        {
            wordList[i] = new char[32];
            inputFile >> wordList[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: There may be some other variations on that theme, but yes, that's what you have to do. It requires reading the file in a loop and putting into your list.

Comment: it is true , but it is waste of time and memory , to have multiple wordLists @MatsPetersson

Comment: I don't see why you would need more than one dictionary, anyway.

Comment: That is a "programming problem" where "don't do that" is the right answer.

Comment: @shayan 1) can you use std::string ? 2) do you want 1 static wordlist and n dictionalies using the same ? or do you want several wordlists (for example 1 per language) static in size ?

Comment: @Christophe 1) yes 2)a static wordlist with n dics using same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve the programming problem.

Here's my suggestion:

Move the `static` members out of the class.

```
class Dictionary
{
   public:
      Dictionary();
      bool lookUp(const char *)const;
   private:
      void  suggestion(const char *)const;
};
```

In the .cpp file, use:

```
static const int SIZE = 109582;
static std::vector<std::string> wordList(SIZE);

static int initializeWordList(std::string const& filename)
{
   // Do the needul to initialize the wordList.
}

Dictionary::Dictionary()
{
   static int init = initializeWordList("wordsEn.txt");
}
```

This will make sure that the word list is initialized only once, regardless of how may instances of `Dictionary` you create.

Comment: how about making the word list as an independent data type ? and then use it as static?

Comment: You could, if you need any functionality that is not provided by the standard library.